# Jquery fadeIn and fadeOut not working, how to properly create fadein animation with addclass and mouseover?

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation

The base idea is, I have shop menu as list

```
<li class="shop-menu"><a href="{{url('shop')}}">shop</a></li>
```

when the shop-menu hovered (mouseover jquery function), I want to fadeIn a div I name it

```
shop-menu-div
```

I have successfully pop-up this menu without fade-in animation by having css display:none and then display:contents when hovered by addClass('active)

the thing is, I want this shop-menu-div to fadeIn when hovered and fadeout when mouseleave

have tried several things even with css keyframes but it's not working, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add event listeners for the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events... 
JQuery using css() method:

EDIT You wanted a fade, sorry use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

```js
let $menu = $('.shop-menu');
let $show = $('#shop-menu-div');
$menu.mouseover(function() {  
    $show.fadeIn('slow');
})
$menu.mouseleave(function() { 
    $show.fadeOut('slow');

})
```

```css
#shop-menu-div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="shop-menu"><a href="{{url('shop')}}">shop</a></li>

<div id="shop-menu-div">Show this div on hover</div>
```

JQUERY: You could also toggle between classes as well using a CSS transition for your opacity

```js
let $menu = $('.shop-menu');
let $show = $('#shop-menu-div');
$menu.mouseover(function() {
  $show.addClass('block').removeClass('none');
})
$menu.mouseleave(function() {
  $show.removeClass('block').addClass('none');

})
```

```css
.none {
 -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.block {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="shop-menu"><a href="{{url('shop')}}">shop</a></li>

<div id="shop-menu-div" class="none">Show this div on hover</div>
```

Comment: the animation works now thank you but the link is  now not clickable

Comment: I have no ideas why, try go google it and someone said because of the <li> tag, tried removed it, still not working

Comment: does fadein jquery makes html attribute become preventdefault?

Comment: Nothing mentioned in the documentation on JQuery API about preventDefault on either `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()`. The link in the test example works fine before or after the fade when clicking the link. Did you get it work?

Comment: hi dale, thanks for your help it works now, it was the stupid z-index

Answer (score 0):

with display you can't fade it, try `opacity:1` and `opacity:0` with a transition and you could do it even without jQuery pure css
or for jQuery try 
`$("#myDiv").animate({opacity:0},speed,callback)`

Comment: No problem, jQuery is quite easy but I would advice you to use as much as possible CSS it's lighter ;)

Comment: I see, thank you, I'm quite new too with the jquery, though I agree with you css is lighter, but I think we can take further query, cheers!